# Specifying Model of Alternative Hypothesis for Calculating Bayes Factors

Tags: bayesian, mixed-model, bayes-factors

I'm new to Bayesian statistics. I'm running a linear mixed effects model in R (using `lmer`), and I want to report Bayes Factors using these results, as demonstrated in Silver,Dienes & Wonnacott (2021). This paper uses a R script version of Dienes' Bayes Factor calculator found here: http://www.lifesci.sussex.ac.uk/home/Zoltan_Dienes/inference/Bayes.htm

I have a question about specifying the model of the alternative hypothesis. In this paper, the authors state that this can be defined with a normal distribution with mean (effect size) 0 and that this makes 'a more stringent test' as it is then harder to discriminate H1 and H0. However, surely an effect size of 0 is impossible in the model of the alternative hypothesis?

Comment: It is under a continuous prior.

Comment: @Xi'an could you elaborate please?